# WPF Listview alternate row background by data group not row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I couldn't find a solution for my problem/idea, and I hope that someone could help me out.
In WPF I have a `CollectionViewSource` depending on an `IEnumerable<Item>`.
An `Item` has the *Name*, *Height*, *Age* fields.
In Xaml, the ListView's `ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewSource.View}"`.

I know, the `Listview` has an `AlternationCount` property which can change the row background color.

But I want to change the row background color only if the *Age* field data is different from the above row's *Age* data.

Like this, ordered by *Age*:

[image: alternate]

The row background color is alternated only when the *Age* data is different.

When I set another sort order to the list, the alternating should also be changed.

In this picture the list is ordered by *Name*:

[image: Alternate color order name]

But the background color depends on the *Age* data.

Is there any way to make a solution for this concept?

Comment: Hmm... my first attempt would be to bind the background color and pass the ItemsSource and the Item to a MultiValueConverter to get the index of the item and then you can check against index - 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this and live life to fullest :

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflow.Window6"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window6" Height="362.03" Width="563.91">

<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CVS" Source="{Binding .}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Age"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <AlternationConverter x:Key="AltCnvKey">
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Snow"/>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightBlue"/>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange"/>
            </AlternationConverter>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Height}" Header="Height"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>           
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle AlternationCount="3">                    
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=GroupItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource AltCnvKey}}"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfStackOverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window6.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window6 : Window
    {
        public Window6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new[] { new { Age = 32, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 34, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 34, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 32, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 32, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 39, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 }, new { Age = 40, Name = "Name1", Height = 6 } }.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried this one too, but I could not implement into my solution. Do not know why, maybe the MVVM.
But thank you very much.

Comment: @HegeGabi My answer uses standard features provided by WPF itself, and no extra logic.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am not perfect in WPF.
I tried your code, but there is no items in the ListView.
I am using ResourceDictionary->MainSkin.xaml, put in there the PropertyGroupDescription and change the Binding to the List from MainViewModel. There are no datas in ListView.
When I try to put the DataContext part into the code behind, it gives me an error message: 'IndexerProperty' problem.

And yes, it works great, if I tried it in a separated window.
Thank you for your code and suggestion, I will keep on trying.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, I have made it work! :-)
Bit unfortunatelly, it is slow, when the ListView has hundreds of rows. Can I speed up the coloring somehow?
Thanks.

Comment: @HegeGabi Look for virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`RelativeSource.PreviousData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.previousdata) for your task.

First, create an `IMultivalueConverter` which will accept the values you want to compare and return the current alternation index based on them:

```
class ComparisonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private int currentAlternation = 0;
    public int AlternationCount { get; set; } = 2;

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO: exception handling
        if (values.Distinct().Count() != 1)
        {
            if (++currentAlternation >= AlternationCount)
            {
                currentAlternation = 0;
            }
        }

        return currentAlternation;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This converter accepts multiple values and returns an unchanged alternation index when all values are equal; otherwise, it first changes the alternation index to the next one and then returns a new index.

Now, create a `MultiBinding` that will provide the alternation index value to the `Style`, where you define your colors:

```
<!-- This is an incomplete ListView! Set the View and ItemsSource as required. -->
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:ComparisonConverter x:Key="ComparisonConverter"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- This is the DataTrigger for the alternation index 1 -->
                <DataTrigger Value="1">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ComparisonConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Age"/>
                            <Binding Path="Age" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource PreviousData}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

So in this style, the default Color for the alternation index 0 is Wheat. Using the `DataTrigger`, the alternation index 1 will generate the color Red.

The sort order changes will be reflected automatically, because the `CollectionViewSource` will rebuild the view, so the `ListView` will create all items from scratch using the `MultiBinding` for each item.

Comment: Hello!
I tried this one too, but I could not implement into my solution. Do not know why, maybe the MVVM.

Comment: Sorry I messed up.
I use this one, and it works very well.

Comment: And one more question.
I am using MVVM with DoFocus to the List. ANd every time, when list get back the focus, the background colorization is rerun.
How can I make that  the row color is run only when the ItemsSource list is change - remove or add item to the list?